# finding if a linear transformation exists, and proving it.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, transformation

We just started the topic of linear transformations and I have this hw question that I just don't understand.

**Does there exist a non-trivial linear transformation, represented by some 2x2 matrix,
which maps the entire Cartesian plane to the line $L = \{(x,y)\mid x = y\}$**

I read up on some of the other linear transformation questions on this website but they were pretty specific questions. Could someone give me the general idea on how to solve a question asking for the existence of a linear transformation and how to prove it?  Also an explanation on how to approach this problem would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you just take the perpendicular projection of the point $(x,y)$ in the plane on the line passing through origin at angle of $45$ degrees, that will be it. Try to figure out, how can you write in form of transformation algebraically

Answer (score 1):

You can always define a linear transformation by defining what it does to a basis.  In your case $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ are a basis for $\mathbb{R}^2$.  Just define a linear transformation by deciding where on the line $y=x$ they should go.

Comment: Just so I understand. Do you mean manipulating the basis matrix so that when you do the transformation it maps to y = x?

Comment: Just send $(1,0)$ to some vector on the line $y=x$ and do the same for $(0,1)$.  You can pick any two vectors on $y=x$ that you'd like.  The corresponding matrix will have as first column the vector to which you sent $(1,0)$ and as second column the vector to which you sent $(0,1)$.